# How to access one usercontrol to another control using c#?

Tags: c#

I have two user controller test1.ascx & test2.ascx. How to access test1.ascx within test2.ascx.

Example:
test1.ascx.cs
I have follwing method:

```
Public string test()
{
   return "Welcome to user control 1";
}
```

In test2.axcs.cs

```
public void Page_Load(object obj, sender e)
    {
       test1();
    }

public string test1()
   {
        return "Welcome to user control 2";
   }
```

I would like to access second user control(test2.ascx.cs) within test1.ascx.cs.

Please help me to solve.

Comment: How I can call call test2.ascx page_load event from my test1.ascx. In my parent page is abc.aspx. So, I registered test1.ascx in my abc.aspx parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You can register test2.ascx in test1.ascx
test1.ascx

```
<%@ Register Src="test2.ascx" TagName="Temp2" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<uc2:Temp2 ID="Temp21" runat="server" />
```

test1.ascx.cs

```
Public string test()
{
   return Temp21.test1; // The output will be "Welcome to user control 2"
}
```

Comment: if it's possible to call test2.ascx.cs page_load event within test1.ascx.cs.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. How about you encapsulate it within one public method and call it through test1.ascx.cs . I think Microsoft set that rules (Page_Load to be protected) with something in mind.

Comment: else if it's possbile to refresh test2.ascx user control within test1.ascx.

Comment: Because I have one telerik:listbbox in test2.ascx. In test1.ascx while click save button i have to refresh test2.ascx listbox and reload the listbox items only without reload entire page.

Comment: I said before, if it is public method, you can call it from any ascx (if those ascxs or it's derived class in one page) Just call method to refresh your telerik list(in test2) and call in on save button click in (test1) like I post before.